# Characters and dimensions

Tags: group-theory

I was looking at one of the problems in the book, "Algebra" by Artin which states:

Find the dimension of the irreducible representations of the octahedral group, dihedral groups $D_5$ and $D_6$.

From, what I remember, the dimension can be determined by the character table. But what can be the character table of the octahedral group? It has no particular relations. Also, for $D_5$ and $D_6$ is there another way to compute the dimension other than the character table?

Comment: What are you allowed to assume?  Since the dihedral groups act as reflections and rotations, you can figure out some of the representations by hand.

Comment: $D_5$ is small enough to get away with.  Are you familiar with the conjugacy class structure of $D_5$?  Are you aware that the number of conjugacy classes is equal to the number of irreducible characters?  And finally, that the order of the group is equal to the sum of the squares of the character degrees?  That's all you need to finish $D_5$.

Comment: @Doc: Oh yes.. I do see a theorem proved stating the same results mentioned above. Thus, $D_5$ and $D_6$ will be similar. Can we do a similar approach for octahedral groups too?

Comment: Absolutely.  There are a few more tricks I can share.  I interpret the octahedral group to be the isometries of the cube (easier ro think about the cube than the icosahedron, and their isometry groups are the same since they are dual).  See my answer below, and let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @user104221 one additional point.  The full isometry group of the cube (and icosahedron) has $48$ elements, and is also called the binary octahedral group.  I (and, I believe, Artin) is referring to its index two subgroup of order $24$..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this will only work on groups of small order.

$D_5$ has only four conjugacy classes:  They are comprised, respectively, of 
1) identity
2) two rotations
3) two other rotations
4) five reflections

This means $D_5$ has exactly four irreducible characters.  Let their degrees be $d_1=1$, $d_2$, $d_3$, $d_4$.  Assume $d_{i}\le d_{i+1}$.

Then  $10 = |D_5|= 1^2 + d_2^2 + d_3^3 +d_4^2$.

The only possibility is $d_2=1$, $d_3=2$, $d_4=2$.

Let me add: If you want to apply this technique to $D_6$ and the octahedral group, note that $D_6$ has has order $12$ and $6$ conjugacy classes, and the octahedral group has order $24$ and $5$ conjugacy classes.

Comment: I understand it now. And have been able to tackle the other 2 problems successfully too. Thank you.